# Is this what I need?

Tags: security

I tried to make an overseas payment using my Debit Card and it wouldn't go through. The error said "Did not pass gateway filter".

My question is, is Tor what I need to bypass this filter?

I have tried to put this question in various different ways but cannot find a suitable answer so my apologies if I'm duplicating anything.

Answer (score 1):

It’s difficult to say without knowing more details. In general using Tor often makes it more difficult to make purchases online since some payment processors will classify Tor traffic as fraudulent. In your case, the service is probably not set up to process your type of debit card. You may have more success using a credit card if possible. If they’re preventing the transaction based on your location, then Tor might help if you use an exit node from the same country. But if this is the case, then a VPN would be better since you have more control over your “exit”, and you don’t need the anonymity features of Tor.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've tried with credit cards as well & I've got a couple of other people to try but nothing works. There aren't any restrictions on any of my cards & i use them for overseas payments regularly. It may have to end up as one of life's mysteries! I am considering using Bitcoins instead but I need to read more about them first. Thank you again for your help.